# Remove Nodes Depending on Dynamic ID, C#, XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, nodes

I have this XML File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Mobiles>
  <Mobile ID="98a2d0b9c2661725a7486423ebd94abdef53ed89051ff5ac7a9c63a4b2a99d7a" RegDate="26/05/2017">
    <FullName>Galaxy S-4</FullName>
    <Vendor>Samsung</Vendor>
    <Date>2010</Date>
    <Price>30000SYP</Price>
    <Weight>5g</Weight>
    <Features>All</Features>
    <Notifecations></Notifecations>
    <Picture>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</Picture>
  </Mobile>
  <Mobile ID='00283f5aa9c0c68c342c02977051757a7faae0ee70b086e628da7cc5baef2100' RegDate="26/05/2017">
    <FullName>6600</FullName>
    <Vendor>Nokia</Vendor>
    <Date>2006</Date>
    <Price>200SYP</Price>
    <Weight>10g</Weight>
    <Features>blutooth</Features>
    <Notifecations></Notifecations>
    <Picture>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</Picture>
  </Mobile>
</Mobiles>
```

When I try to remove Mobile element depending on IDtextbox.text rather than static value in XPath expression it doesn't execute

I'm using Windows application in Visual Studio 2010, C# language

I need two examples:
1- Depending on an element inside the parent element.
2- depending on an attribute of the parent element, make sure that attribute is not an integer value, it's code.
Notice: I have searched for many websites and view multiple solutions nobody mention about using control value in XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq which is better in this case than xpath

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> mobiles = doc.Descendants("Mobile").ToList();

            mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Element("FullName") != "Galaxy S-4").ToList();

            mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("RegDate") != "26/05/2017").ToList();

            doc.Descendants("Mobiles").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(new XElement("Mobiles", mobiles));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but you give me an example using static value rather dynamic (IDTXTBX.Text), and with ReplaceWith instead of remove
I change it to this shape, but still not working, it removes everything
mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == ID).ToList();
using this code it must remove just first one if I change the ID attribute to element inside Mobile node

Comment: mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == ID).ToList();
ID here is a string variable

Comment: thanks, Mr.jdweng
I solve the problem with this code

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Mobiles.xml");
    List<XElement> mobiles = doc.Descendants("Mobile").ToList();
    //mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == ID).ToList();
    mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == ID).ToList();
    doc.Descendants("Mobile").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith();

Best regards

Comment: I string is a string is a string.  You can always replace a static value with a variable just like you did.  I just gave a example of the linq needed like you requested.

Comment: sorry but it's not working again, it always removes the first node.
but to be attention, When I try to remove using Elements inside the node, it's working.
xdoc.XPathSelectElement("Mobiles/Mobile[FullName =" + FullNameTXTBX.Text + "]").Remove();
as you can see I'm using Xpath again

Comment: When Use this Code (xdoc.XPathSelectElement("Mobiles/Mobile[@ID = " + IDTXTBX.Text + "]").Remove();)
it gives me this Error
'Mobiles/Mobile[@ID = 00283f5aa9c0c68c342c02977051757a7faae0ee70b086e628da7cc5baef2100 ]' has an invalid token.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, Mr.jdweng
I solve the problem with this code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Mobiles.xml");
List<XElement> mobiles = doc.Descendants("Mobile").ToList();
//mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == ID).ToList();
mobiles = mobiles.Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == ID).ToList();
doc.Descendants("Mobile").FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith();
```

Best regards

Comment: Last line will always remove all the Mobile elements from document which is not what you want.  In some cases when you get a match you want to keep these elements in the document.